# connect to ms-sql from python, tried in several ways but no luck

Tags: python, freetds

I am trying with `pyodbc` and `freetds`, but `freetds` can't be installed. I got an error like:

```
==> Installing homebrew/versions/freetds091
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.freetds.org/pub/freetds/stable/freetds-0.91.112.tar.gz


curl: (28) Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
Error: Failed to download resource "freetds091"
```

Comment: Given the instant timeout, I'm wondering if maybe you've got a firewall blocking FTP connections. I can reach that URL just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to edit the formula to replace the ftp address with an http address..

```
brew edit freetds
```

This will open the FreeTDS formula. Replace the line starting with `url` with:

```
url "https://fossies.org/linux/privat/freetds-1.00.15.tar.bz2"
```

This will also install the latest / greatest 1.00 version; 0.91 is very out of date. Good luck!